# Ruby "Undefined method 'length' for #<NetAddr::CIDRv4..."

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have an array of three NetAddr::CIDR objects and am attempting to sort them using the `cidr_sort` method of the NetAddr module (http://rubydoc.info/gems/netaddr/1.5.0/NetAddr#cidr_sort-class_method)

When I call the `sort` method from within my Class as follows:

```
Class IPv4SummaryNet
  attr_accessor :component_nets
  @component_nets = []

  def add_net(net)
      @component_nets = component_nets.to_a.push(net)
  end

  def sort_component_nets
      component_nets_sorted = @component_nets.sort
  end
  ...
end
```

I get the following error: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/netaddr-1.5.0/lib/cidr_shortcuts.rb:216:in 'cidr_sort': undefined method 'length' for #<NetAddr::CIDRv4:0x007f55cbae0088> (NoMethodError)`

But if I print the array length from within my program, I get the correct value of 3.

I have also tried using `sort_by` and `NetAddr::cidr_sort(@component_nets)` and get the same error.

Why is Ruby telling me `length` is undefined when the `cidr_sort` method tries to call it, yet I can call it in my code with no problem?

Comment: The error is not for a missing method in the `Array`, but rather in an instance of `NetAddr::CIDRv4`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `@component_nets` is an `array` of `NetAddr::CIDRv4` objects being passed to the `cidr_sort` method. `cidr_sort` then calls the `length` method on the `array`

Comment: Evidently not - either you do not pass what you think you pass, or the method doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: I'm passing exactly what the documentation for the NetAddr module says the method is looking for, but apparently the method does not do what the documentation claims. I'm just going to write my own method to sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def sort_component_nets
      component_nets_sorted = @component_nets.sort
  end
```

Here Ruby thinks you are trying to create a local variable within the method block, but I assume that you actually want to access the method component_nets_sorted that is outside the block. To do this: you must add the self. prefix to it.

```
  def sort_component_nets
      self.component_nets_sorted = @component_nets.sort
  end
```

Comment: I am trying to create a local variable within the method block